# Not able to connect oracle Database while using Cluster type HOST

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I'm facing the following errors while connecting oracle DB, **I'm using spring boot JDBC template to connect to database.** The errors are below,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at com.falabella.util.OracleDB.main(OracleDB.java:70)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:392)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: NODE-01: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Below are my finding, My database server host having the cluster and it has two nodes, like below,

```
   Cluster (wood.clsuter.com)
     |  NODE01 (wood-01)
     |  NODE02 (wood-02)
```

My connection string is like this, jdbc:oracle:thin:@wood-clsuter.com:1531/service_name

When I'm using the cluster name in the connection string, I'm facing the below error

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: wood-01: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Whereas if I use any of the node name in the connection string , able to connect Data base without any issue, the working connection string is like below,
`jdbc:oracle:thin:@wood-01.com:1531/service_name`         or
`jdbc:oracle:thin:@wood-02.com:1531/service_name`

Since I need to use my DB requests as load balancing, I need to use the cluster name instead of slave nodes,

I would like to know the root cause of this issue, such kind of production environment issues,

Could you please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change connect string to:

```
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(FAILOVER=ON)(LOAD_BALANCE=ON)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=wood-01.com)(PORT = 1531))(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = wood-02.com)(PORT = 1531)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME =service_name)(FAILOVER_MODE=(TYPE=select)(METHOD=basic))))"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I would like to know, how this would be working functionality

How the address_list will work? 
If the first address fails, then it would try to connect the second one?
or always it would try to connect a random address?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/tnsnames.htm#NETRF273